# Trouble loading images in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I have 2 windowsForms lets call them form1 and form2. form1 consists of a picturebox and a button. When I click on the button form2 opens. Now form2 consists of a grid and depending on the position on which I have clicked on the grid the x and y coordinates are returned to form1. Based on these coordinates I add an image to the pictureBox. But the image isn't getting added! Is there something I am missing here?

> Code inside the mouseDownEvent in form2

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.openImage(x,y);
```

> Code in form1

```
internal void openImage(int x, int y)
    {
        string ogFileName = "r" + x.ToString() + "c" + y.ToString();
        string imageFilePath = ogFileName  + "." + extension;
        MessageBox.Show(imageFilePath); //I can see the correct path here
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
}//extension is a static variable declared outside this function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

This line only creates a new instance of Form1

What you can do is adding a Form1 variable which will reference your current form.

You initialize it in constructor and in the button click you pass it to Form2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Form1 form1; // form1 will store the reference of Form1
   public Form1()
   {
    form1 = this; // We initialize form1 in the constructor
    InitializeComponent();
   }

   // button to open form2
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form2 form2 = new Form2(form1); // We open form2 with form1 as parameter
        form2.Visible = true;
    }


    public void openImage(int x, int y)
    {

    }

}
```

Now in the Form2 you just have to add a Form1 variable that will be initialized in the constructor.

Then you can use it as now it represents the current instance of Form1

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1; // Reference to form1

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1; // We initialize form1
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // we call openimage from form1
        form1.openImage(130, 140);
    }
}
```

I have tested this example with a label and it works fine so I think there should be no problem with a picturebox

Comment: There's no reason to make and fill in that `Form1 form1` variable inside the `Form1` class... you can just use `new Form2(this)`.